# Trying to only echo lines containing string

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a simple line-by-line read of a file and echo all lines containing a match for the user input, the problem is that it shows every line no matter what if anything matches, i'm sure i'm just having a logic brain-fart here, anyone not sleep addled around to take a peek?

```
<?php
$filnavn = "D:\\something\something\something.txt";
$klassekode=$_POST["klassekode"];
$elevarray = file($filnavn);
foreach($elevarray as $elev){
  $strpos=false;
  if (stripos($elev,$klassekode) !== false) {
    echo $elev;
  }
}
?>
```

File example-

```
bob class1
joe class1
dan class2
```

Example 1 (correct)

```
input : horse
output : nothing (correct)
```

Example 2 (incorrect)

```
input : class1
output : 
bob class1
joe class1
dan class2
(everything!)
```

Comment: The output you have listed seems to match the desired output.

Comment: except in the second example with `class1`, `class2` is showing up.

Comment: Try if (stripos($elev,$klassekode) === FALSE) {} else { echo $elev; } Per http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: @Bradley and the difference is ... ?

Comment: @Cheery per the php manual: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: After reading the code, nothing appeared wrong. So I made an example and it is working as intended. [Incorrect example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Nw7xkJ)

Comment: @Bradley do you know what `!== false` means?

Comment: @Bradley OP is using `!==` which is the opposite of `===` so they are already using the type safe comparisson.

Comment: @Norse are you sure that input is `class1` and not just `class` or something shorter? Look at output of `var_dump($_POST["klassekode"]);`

Comment: Cannot reproduce either, can you post an example on for example http://codepad.viper-7.com/?

Comment: @Cheery yep, thats enough for me, gonna go get more coffee I suppose, apologies all.

Comment: I think the problem may lie in it reading the source file incorrectly now that I think about it. EDIT: could foreign characters (Æ Ø Å) have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Norse `var_dump($elevarray);` and check it out.

Comment: Var dump returns 
    array(1) { [0]=> string(89) "bob, bob, class1
    joe, joe, class1
    dan, dan, class2
    " }

Oh dear.

Just realized I may be an idiot and I perhaps used HTML breaks instead of n and the file may be a runon line. And I didn't even realize because I was reading the output on a website and it was translating the line breaks. Coffee supply dwindling.

Comment: YUP THAT WAS IT.
Coffee supply empty, code functioning as intended, now to resolve coffee problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `preg_match()` function inside of the `foreach` loop, as follows:

```
foreach( $elevarray as $elev ){                                                                                                                                                            
    if( preg_match("/$klassekode/i", $elev) === 1){
        echo $elev;                       
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) there is no need in regexp 2) you should use `preg_quote` to escape string from user